# Bluestacks return to home screen on Image Change in Image View

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, android-drawable

I just started learning Android. What I'm trying to do is to change the image inside the image view on button click. I don't see any syntax error or anything on Android Studio. The app runs fine and displays the first image. However, as soon as I click on the `Button` to change the image, it goes blank and returns to the bluestacks homescreen.

Here's my code.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Spinner_ListView_MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView myImageView;
    Button myChangeButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner__list_view__main);

        myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
        myChangeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myChangeButton);
        myChangeButton.setOnClickListener(new myChangeButtonListener());
        myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.androidone);
    }

    private class myChangeButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (myImageView.getBackground().equals(R.drawable.androidone)) {
                myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.androidtwo);
            } else {
                myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.androidone);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Both `androidone.png` and `androidtwo.png` exists inside the `drawable` folder.
I noticed that the same behavior occurs when there's an incorrect casting of `doubles` and `int`

What could be causing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are getting an exception. Isn't there any error in Logcat?

I think you should check drawable in ImageView this way:

`if(myImageView.getDrawable().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidone, null)))`

ImageView.getBackground() would not return that what are you looking for.